# SASS mixin : how to add class before?

Tags: css, sass

I'm struggling with creating a mixin with sass and I can't seem to find a solution. If anyone has any ideas...
I have something like this:

```
.tata {
        font-size: 12px;
        .toto{
            display: block;
            .tutu {
                text-align: left;
                @include mixin_test{
                    background: red;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

and I'd like to have something like this when compiled:

```
 html .tata .toto .tutu {background:red}
```

I've tried this, but the result is not what I expected:

```
@mixin mixin_test {
    html{
        @content;   
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You use `less` in title and `sass` in question, and tag it with both - which is it?

Comment: Oups, sorry,
I use sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your mixin. Missing **&** after the selector:

```
@mixin mixin_test {
    html & {
        @content;   
    }
}

.tata {
        font-size: 12px;
        .toto{
            display: block;
            .tutu {
                text-align: left;
                @include mixin_test{
                    background: red;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

On this page you can read more about parent selector: [Parent Selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector)

Comment: Thank you so much ❤️ . It's perfect !